# Php - bulk email sending using elastic mailmerge

Tags: php, mailmerge

What are the disadvantages of using elastic mail api (using php) to send bulk emails?Is it possible to send HTML emails(ie mail containing images) with this api

Comment: @moose It doesn't help that the PHP logo is in lower case.  See http://php.net/download-logos.php.

Comment: @DonCruickshank: I understand that people write 'php' instead of 'PHP'. But I don't understand why they write 'Php' or 'PhP'. Always when I see questions like these, it seems to me that people don't even take the time to read their question again before submitting them.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason you integrating the Elastic Mail API?

In terms of a future-proof bulk email service, you may want to look into [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/)

It does support HTML (with whatever you fancy) and is also very inexpensive.

> If you are an Amazon EC2 user, you can start sending with Amazon SES
>   for free. You can send 62,000 messages per month to any recipient when
>   you call Amazon SES from an Amazon EC2 instance directly or through
>   AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Additionally, you can also receive 1,000
>   messages per month for free on Amazon SES. Many applications are able
>   to operate entirely within this free tier limit, and it does not
>   expire after a year.
>   https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/

To send bulk email, you can call the SendEmail or SendRawEmail API operations repeatedly for each email you want to send. Software running on Amazon EC2, Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR), or your own servers can compose and deliver bulk emails using Amazon SES in whatever way best suits your needs.

You can also send bulk email using Amazon SES as an SMTP relay.

Comment: Problem with Amazon SES is that it does not allow bulk sending, you have to send each email separately, in best cases you are allowed to group up to 50 contacts in BCC field but if the email was dropped then 50 emails will be dropped at once! Other providers like Mailgun and Elastic email allows you to send to a mailing list and they take care of sending the emails separately.

Comment: Not true. To send bulk email, you can call the SendEmail or SendRawEmail API operations repeatedly for each email you want to send.

Comment: So to send 1000 emails I have to send 1000 requests to the server? Rather than 1 request with 1 list?!